# How to create a reusable UIAlert ActionSheet as an UIViewController extension?

Tags: swift, extension-methods, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet, uialertaction

I would like to create an action sheet that can be used several time in my code. To do so, I need to be able to use functions according to the action sheet title. Is there a way to pass functions as a parameter array like the "title" parameter?

```
//MARK: - UIAlert action sheet title
enum ActionSheetLabel: String {
  case camera = "Camera"
  case photoLibrary = "Album"
  case cancel = "Cancel"
}



class CameraHandler {
static let cameraHandler = CameraHandler()
func openCamera() { }
func openPhotoLibrary() { }
}


//MARK: - Alert that shows an action sheet with cancel
extension UIViewController {
  func showActionSheetWithCancel(vc: UIViewController, title: [ActionSheetLabel] /*Make a function parameter here to match title*/) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

for value in title {
  actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: value.rawValue, style: .default, handler: {
    (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    //Use the parameter function here to match title

  }))
}

actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ActionSheetLabel.cancel.rawValue, style: .cancel, handler: nil))
vc.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey you check my answer if this helpful for you then please accept it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find out the best way to add an action sheet with cancel and as much action as needed.

Create an UIViewController extension with type alias:

```
//MARK: - Alert that shows an action sheet with cancel 
extension UIViewController {
  typealias AlertAction = () -> ()
  typealias AlertButtonAction = (ActionSheetLabel, AlertAction)

  func showActionSheetWithCancel(titleAndAction: [AlertButtonAction]) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

for value in titleAndAction {
  actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: value.0.rawValue, style: .default, handler: {
  (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    value.1()

}))
}
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ActionSheetLabel.cancel.rawValue, style: .cancel, handler: nil))
self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Then, in the class or other place where you want to use it, add the method this way:

```
//MARK: - UIAlert action sheet title
enum ActionSheetLabel: String {
  case camera = "Camera"
  case photoLibrary = "Album"
  case cancel = "Cancel"
}

//MARK: - Class example where to use the action sheet action
class CameraHandler {

fileprivate let currentVC: UIViewController!

func openCamera() { 
// Open user camera
}
func openPhotoLibrary() { 
// Open user photo library
}

  // Method example of this action sheet
  func showActionSheetWithCameraAndLibrary(vc: UIViewController) {

    //This is the way to use the extension
    vc.showActionSheetWithCancel(titleAndAction: [
      (ActionSheetLabel.camera, { [weak self] in self?.openCamera() }),
      (ActionSheetLabel.photoLibrary, { [weak self] in self?.openPhotoLibrary() })
      ])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For UIAlert you just need to change preferredStyle .alert it and it's working for UIAlert And and below code just copy and paste it working for UIActionSheet.

```
 extension UIViewController {
       func popupAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actionTitles:[String?], actionStyle:[UIAlertAction.Style], actions:[((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?]) {
              let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
              for (index, title) in actionTitles.enumerated() {
                   let action = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: actionStyle[index], handler: actions[index])
                   alert.addAction(action)
              }
              self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
    }
```

**Check below code For Usage**

```
self.popupAlert(title: "Alert"), message: “Error in Loading”, actionTitles: ["Okey", "Email"], actionStyle: [.default, .default], actions: [nil,{ action in
         // I have set nil for first button click
         // do your code for second button click
 }])
```

if you have any query then please comment me. Thank You

Comment: No need to pass the vc as a parameter, just use self.present

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a closure  and call it in the handler something like this should work.

Also not  sure why you were passing the `UIViewController` , as you're already defining the function in a `extension UIViewController` therefore i allowed my self to remove it and used `self.present` instead .

```
extension UIViewController {
func showActionSheetWithCancel(title: [ActionSheetLabel], action: @escaping () -> ()?) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    for value in title {
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: value.rawValue, style: .default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
           // action
            action()

        }))
    }
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: ActionSheetLabel.cancel.rawValue, style: .cancel) { (_) in
        action() // or for cancel call it here
    }
    actionSheet.addAction(alertAction)
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)


  }
}
```

As you can see `@escaping () -> ()?` is optional so you can pass `nil` too .

Answer (score 0):

from what I understood you need to call a specific functions when the title of the alert changes & also you want to be able to do so from different viewControllers,
I hope this will help

```
extension UIViewController {

 func showActionSheetWithCancel(vc: UIViewController, title: [ActionSheetLabel] ) {
            let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let cameraHandler = CameraHandler()
            for value in title {

                switch value.rawValue {
                case ActionSheetLabel.camera.rawValue:
                    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ActionSheetLabel.camera.rawValue, style: .default, handler: { (alert) in
                        cameraHandler.openCamera()

                    }))
                case ActionSheetLabel.photoLibrary.rawValue:
                    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ActionSheetLabel.photoLibrary.rawValue, style: .default, handler: { (alert) in

                        cameraHandler.openPhotoLibrary()

                    }))
                default:
                    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ActionSheetLabel.cancel.rawValue, style: .cancel, handler: nil))

                }
                vc.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
}
```

and the call of the function will be like this:

```
 showActionSheetWithCancel(vc: self, title: [UIViewController.ActionSheetLabel.camera])
```